# "Ok Google" and Localization

Tags: android

all apps can be started through "Ok Google" or "Hey Google" by saying the words (in english) "Open ..." i.e. if my app's name is "Graphic Dashboard", then I say "Ok Google" (pause 1-2 seconds while the app is starting), then "Open Graphic Dashboard", the Assistant's voice then say "Opening Graphic Dashboard" and the app starts.
I have started to develop an app with my language: Italian. When I say "Avvia Riepilogo dati", all is fine.
Then I added a localization in "English USA", added on my real smartphone English usa language, added on google assistant, rebooted, now all my smartphone (Android 10) is running fine on english.

The problem is now: If I say Ok google, the assistant starts, I say "Open Data Summary", nothing happens, or start the web search for "Open Data Summary".

If I say "Open Riepliogo Dati" then my app starts.
I have translated ALL strings with resource editor. The App name in the manifest is translated too.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours it worked. It seems that google assistant needs to be trained to display certain results and to to use a particular result.